# connecting Omniauth with twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-6

I am following this series of Rails tutorials.
Now I am stuck when it comes to connecting the users to Twitter following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o48-i4m6W78&feature=emb_title&ab_channel=GoRails
. Connecting to twitter works fine but there is no active records of users in the database like it's explained in the video as you can see at 7:32 by the instructor, the instructor database has activerecords of user.twitter_accounts but mine gives me nil and it doesn't have activerecords at all as it's shown in the image. I tried different ways but none seem to work, so I hope my question clear and simple, regards.

The code below:
omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
  def twitter
    Current.user.twitter_accounts.create(
      name: auth.info.name,
      username: auth.info.nickname,
      image: auth.info.image,
      token: auth.credentials.token,
      secret: auth.credentials.secret,
    )

    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully connected your account"
  end

  def auth
    request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  end
end
```

twitter_accounts_controller.rb

```
class TwitterAccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @twitter_accounts = Current.user.twitter_accounts
  end
end
```

current.rb

```
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :user
end
```

twitter_account.rb

```
class TwitterAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :twitter_accounts
  has_secure_password

  #To validate and prevent from making email empty
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/, message: "must be a vaild email address" }
end
```

https://ibb.co/74T6GNn

Comment: Would you maybe provide some code? Or are we supposed to rewatch the instructors' video? Did you try asking the instructor first?

Comment: I just provided the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new user and then connecting to twitter.